# Python 2.7 reduce lambda statement conversion to list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I was examining a code written in python but I got confused with the following line.

```
return ( reduce(lambda x, y: x + y[0],myList, 0)/len(Actions), )
```

This code takes x and y as an input sums x and y's first element. After that  I think it reduces myList to the value of x+y[0] . How can I accomplish this with using list comprehension instead of using lambda.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on what [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) does?

Comment: `reduce` uses your `lambda` and repeat it on all elements from `myList` - every time it reduce two elements into one element.

Comment: Yes and I already explained what reduce does. What I need is converting this to a list comprehension. I come from a java background so I am not familiar with this terms.

Comment: `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y[0],myList, 0)` ==  `sum(y[0] for y in myList)` or other `sum( [y[0] for y in myList] )`

Comment: This is correct, I upvoted it but the [ symbol before y[0] is wrong I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part that corresponds well to a list comprehension is what the reducing function does with its second argument `y`:

```
tmp = [ y[0] for y in myList ]
```

The reducing function then combines this list one element at a time with the "accumulator" `x`:

```
x = 0  # The third argument to reduce
tmp = [ y[0] for y in myList ]
for y in tmp:
    x += y
```

or more simply

```
x = 0
for y in myList:
    x += y[0]
```

or, as you have probably recognized by now

```
sum(y[0] for y in myList)
```

Comment: I understood the code you and furas wrote but I still have a little problem in understanding  what 0 means in myList,0. Also there is a  /lengthOfList in there. So my new list should be defined by myList = sum(y[0] for y in myList) and my return value should be  myList / len(Actions). Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly right. Regarding the 0, it's just the value passed as the `x` argument the first time the function is called. Without a third argument, the function is called on the first two list items first, then on the previous result and the next list element on successive calls. Put another way, `reduce(f, lst) == reduce(f, lst[1:], lst[0])`. (Note this means that without a third argument, the list cannot be empty; `reduce` raises a `TypeError` in that case.)

Comment: It seems my comment to you had one mistake. Since there is a ,[] at the end of the line I should return  [myList/lenActions(), []). I accept your answer